# Recuperar el color de una tabla color y mandar a pintar en la columna correspondiente

Tags: vb.net

Deseo recuperar el color de una tabla color y mandar a pintar en la columna correspondiente por ejemplo para cuando vuelva abrir la aplicacion me cargue los colores en este como lo que adjunto estoy trabajando con SQL 2012 Y VB.NET componente (DevExpress)

De esta manera tengo organizado la color( columna color es tipo integer) : ID Columna Color

De esta manera mando a pintar las columnas:

```
Private Sub V_quincenaII_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles V_quincenaII.RowCellClick Dim cd As New ColorDialog()

If e.Column.AbsoluteIndex = 1 Then
    If cd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        V_quincenaII.Columns(1).AppearanceCell.BackColor = cd.Color
        V_quincenaII.Columns(1).OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True
        registrarColor(cd.Color.ToArgb, 1, Me.cmbMes.EditValue, txtano.EditValue)
    End If
End If .....
If e.Column.AbsoluteIndex = 16 Then If cd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then V_quincenaII.Columns(16).AppearanceCell.BackColor = cd.Color V_quincenaII.Columns(16).OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True registrarColor(cd.Color.ToArgb, 16, Me.cmbMes.EditValue, txtano.EditValue) End If End If

end sub
```

De esta manera mando a guardar el color de esa columna:

```
Public Sub registrarColor(ByVal color As Integer, Columna As Integer, mes As Integer, ano As Integer) Try Using con As New SqlConnection(Rutina.CadenaConexion()) con.Open()

        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Colores(Color,columna,id_mes,ano) VALUES (@color,@columna,@mes,@ano)"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", color)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columna", Columna)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mes", mes)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ano", ano)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Me.G_quincenaII.DataSource = Deduccion.ListQuincena_II(Me.cmbMes.EditValue, txtano.EditValue)
        MessageBox.Show("Color guardado!")
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
```

Estoy haciendo las acciones en este orden:

1) Abra la aplicación. Haga clic en una celda para abrir la `ColorDialog`. Seleccionar un color y cerrar el diálogo.

2) El color seleccionado se aplica a una columna a la que pertenece la célula se hace clic. Está utilizando el  `GridColumn.AppearanceCell.BackColor`  propiedad para este propósito.

3) Guarde el color seleccionado a otra tabla en su base de datos.

4) Volver a empezar la aplicación. Los colores que tiene en esa tabla se deben aplicar a las columnas.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta repetida http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27135/retrieve-the-color-of-a-colored-table-and-send-to-paint-in-the-corresponding-col, @jose podrias eliminarla

Comment: Mejor deja esta y borra la otra, esta quedó mejor formulada.

Comment: Mas alla del lio de preguntas duplicadas, cual es el problema en si?

Answer (score 0):

El inconveniente es que no estás hacendo el SELECT de la información guardada en la BD en el momento de "pintar" la tabla; deberías cargar o traer la las columnas guardadas en la BD y realizar un loop (ciclo) en el momento de "pintar" la tabla con los valores traídos de la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi de esta manera primero creo una archivo .xml
 Private _file As String = "gridLayout1.xml"
 que ahi me va guarda el color de la columna del grid.

Luego creo a una  Funcion

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As EventArgs)       V_Quincena.OptionsLayout.Columns.StoreAppearance = True
        If File.Exists(_file) Then
            V_Quincena**.RestoreLayoutFromXml**(_file)
        End If
    End Sub
  que me va a validar si el archivo .xml tiene color o no si tine lo recupera sino sale y lo recupera con una porpiedad  que recibe el nombre archivo .xml como parametro que se llama **.RestoreLayoutFromXml**

Luego la mando a guardar el color en el archivo .xml con una funccion

Protected Overrides Sub OnClosing(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
        V_Quincena.**SaveLayoutToXml(_file)**
    End Sub

Con una propiedad que recibe como parametro el nombre del archivo .xml que se llama SaveLayoutToXml(_file)

Saludos .